# How to Avoid adding duplicates to U-SQL Tables

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Is there a way to avoid adding duplicate records in U-SQL tables other than adding/truncating partitions. Let's assume only unique identifiers are different for both records.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use ROWNUMBER() in the U-SQL query

```
@transactions =
   SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM @searchlog;

@result =
   SELECT Id,Name,Description,Age
   FROM @transactions
   WHERE RowNumber == 1;
```

This will get the unique record in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Since U-SQL tables do not provide UNIQUE constraints due to the limited scalability, you will have to make sure that you use `ANTI SEMIJOIN` on the unique columns to filter out the possible duplicates on the new data before you insert it.